# HTML DOM events

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, dom-events

I have a browser tree as below. Each node is a div element with individual id. I want to change the style when the mouse hovers over the node. And do something when the user left-clicks or right-clicks the node. 
[image]

Question1: Some documents say there are performance issues with the :hover selector. So I listen for the mouseover and mouseout events instead. Is this manner recommended?

To implement my requirements, I want to listen for the mouseover, mouseout, click and contextmenu events of each node. I have two solutions. The first is bind the event handler to each node. The second is only bind the event handler to the root node. When the event is bubbled to the root node, the handler is called.

Question 2: Which performance is better about the two solutions?

Comment: Why would you set up a hover effect using JS? Isn't that a task for CSS, which hasn't any performance problems (at least not without using multiple transitions).

Comment: It is recommended that "Avoid the :hover pseudo-selector for non-link elements for IE clients." Copy from the here (developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS will generally outperform JavaScript for hover, it's more native, and it's by far easier to maintain (performance is not limited to client technology, what about the performance of the human maintaining the code?).

Simulating hover effects in JavaScript is sometimes necessary for support in older browsers, depending on the HTML used (if you use `:hover` on links it's always fine).

Event bubbling will perform better than multiple event handler instances.  http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/eventdelegation/

You should never use hover to expand/collapse new content however, that's just inaccessible, expand/collapse should always be triggered from a click event on a link element (it doesn't sound like you are, by the way).

Comment: It is recommended that "Avoid the :hover pseudo-selector for non-link elements for IE clients." Copy from the here (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering). Quotes: [Avoid the :hover pseudo-selector for non-link elements for IE clients.
If you use :hover on non-anchor elements, test the page in IE7 and IE8 to be sure your page is usable.   If you find that :hover is causing performance issues, consider conditionally using a JavaScript onmouseover event handler for IE clients.
]

Comment: I know, but I'd always use links for hoverable items on the grounds of accessibility (keyboard / touch screen).  Performance issues would only be present if your CSS selectors are too vague.

Comment: Thanks Lee. Does the :hover issue only exist for IE? What about Chrome, Safari and Firefox? Do you happen to know that?

Comment: It's been reliable in the other major browsers for a long time, if not since they were created.